# Acer Aspire Z5610 Touchscreen All-in-One Dual Boot

Tags: wireless, keyboard, dual-boot, touchscreen

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on Wubi in a Windows 7 environment.

After successful installation and reboot, I am presented with the dual-boot prompt as expected.

However, my keyboard/mouse are wireless, I cannot choose between OSs; stuck with Windows 7.
Obviously, the touch screen does not repond at dual-boot point.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you enter BIOS using wireless keyboard? Is USB Keyboard enabled in BIOS (if available)?

Comment: At the cost of sounding dumb, I will still attempt: How about changing which OS the computer defaults to? That's not too difficult to do.
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/switching/dualboot-custom.html#dualboot-custom-bootorder

Answer (score 2):

This one is not Ubuntu's fault. It's a problem with your computer's BIOS not using the wireless keyboard and mouse as it should. When this happens, your options become very limited. The most practical one is to simply buy a wired keyboard. You can also change witch OS boots first by booting to Windows 7 and typing `msconfig` in the start menu search box. Run the program, select the startup tab, and move Ubuntu up or down. The problem with this is that when the computer reboots and boots into Ubuntu, Ubuntu can't change the Windows 7 bootloader settings to allow you back into Windows again. So, hunt around in your BIOS settings and see if you can find something that enables the USB keyboard. If not, buy a wired keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but thought if any one else has this problem, I have the same pc and what I do is unplug the USB keyboard, mouse dongle and then instantly plug it back in, works for me.